# How to add controls into a DNN page in .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

How to add controls into a DNN page in .Net??

I tried for this -
I have created my page from the control panel and now wants to add my control on the same page in the content panel how to do,,,,
I went from Host->Module Definition-->Create Definition but not getting the option to add control there... and page is automatically refreshing

But still not getting where to find out the option for add a new control on the same page...
please help me :(

how to render a control on to a DNN page in ASP.NET

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Regarding the menu you used, I guess you have an old version of DNN. In recent versions, this menu is replaced by "Host > Extensions".

Comment: In a subfolder of "DesktopModules", create your ascx inheriting from DotNetNuke.Entities.Module.PortalModuleBase, compile it in your DNN bin folder. Register it in a module definition with the corresponding control folder. Add this module in a page using the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick start to get to know just how to do what you want:
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki?TabId=1409&Page=DotNetNuke-5-Hello-World

Then if you want to learn more about DotNetNuke modules developement, I recommand you look at the Beginning Module Development Video Series section at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Module-Development

Comment: Thanks Daniel Valadas :)

Comment: Actually I am a new in DNN and just now got a supporting project to maintain the some pages and needs to create some new pages so it is bit difficult for me to find out the older controls & new too ..Thank you all for your quick response :)